# Symfony2 XmlFileLoader Invalid Schema error?

Tags: php, symfony

I've heard great things about Symfony so thought I would try download Symfony2 (Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.0.0BETA4.tgz) and have a play with it but I cant get it to run!

I have fixed the usual permission errors etc on /Symfony/web/config.php but when I click:

(Configure your Symfony Application online) or (Bypass configuration and go to the Welcome page)

Then I get a horrible error message saying:

> ErrorException: Warning: DOMDocument::schemaValidateSource(): Invalid Schema in /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php line 357

I dont really understand what this means or how to fix it.

I am running a standard LAMP stack using Zend Server.. Has anyone else experienced this and know how to fix it?

Comment: It seems that editing line 357 to $valid = true;//$dom->schemaValidateSource($source); gets rid of the error. Not exactly a long term solution though. If anyone knows how to actually fix it, that would be hugely appreciated! Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was problem with [corrupted archives](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.php.symfony.users/5588) back in the days of beta. However, a lot has changed since then and everything seems to be working properly now - at least I haven't found any more questions regarding validation being broken in `XmlFileLoader`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this after I did an update. I fixed this by downgrading my version of libxml from libxml2-2.6.26-2.1.21.el5_9.2 to libxml2-2.6.26-2.1.21.el5_9.1.

yum downgrade libxml2-2.6.26-2.1.21.el5_9.1